# Text Distortion with ImageMagick SRT commands

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am please bear with me as I am new to ImageMagick and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction at what could be the cause of this exactly but my issue is this:

I am rendering some text to the image and it works fine unless I rotate the image.

I am using this command for rotation:

```
convert -format jpeg beach.jpg +profile !icc,* ( -background none -size 1698.071388x1698.071388 -gravity center -fill #ffffff -font regular.ttf -stroke none -strokewidth 0 label:Topher +distort SRT 849.035694,849.035694 1 45.275739 2098.879701,1151.202049 ) -flatten -quality 80 jpeg:beach-text.jpg
```

And the Image looks like this [image]

But if I leave rotation alone and my command looks like :

```
convert -format jpeg beach.jpg +profile !icc,* ( -background none -size 1698.071388x1698.071388 -gravity center -fill #ffffff -font regular.ttf -stroke none -strokewidth 0 label:Topher +distort SRT 849.035694,849.035694 1 0.0 2098.879701,1151.202049 ) -flatten -quality 80 jpeg:beach-text.jpg
```

The image comes out as expected:

[image]

As you can see the top of the T is all distorted out of whack. As I've said, I am new to ImageMagick so if there is anything that I am missing that may be of help to tracking down this issue let me know so I can add the info here. Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

P.S. This only seems to happen SOME times.... it isnt always reproducible and happens for letter like "g, j, y" as well at "T".

Upgrading to ImageMagick 7 did not solve the issue. The text is still rendered with that weird preceeding rendering artifact

Comment: It may be a bug but you can use -annotate to create rotated text https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate and possibly -draw I do not know what version of Imagemagick you are using but one of the standard replies on the forum is to update to the latest version. NOTE: The latest version is 7xxx and you may find you need to use magick rather than convert.

Comment: Hmm ok interesting. I will look into your suggestion and thank you for taking the time to read the post. I realized that I am using the same value for both width and height... I have since fixed that and havent been able to reproduce this issue but it seems to be very finicky and doesn't happen all the time anyway so I will still look into your suggestion and continue to play around. Will update this for future reference when the issue is resolved for good. Thanks again

Comment: Updating to 7 didnt do the trick, same issue happens.. Im at a loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive resolved this issue by removing the rotation values from the `+distort SRT` command and leaving that 0 but placing a 
`-rotate [degrees]` command before it. Everything renders as it should now.